# Array from object contain only one result

Tags: php, oop, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and make code like below, why the variable result is different ($mems and $member)

//Topup.php

```
$service = new \Spektr\Libraries\Service;
$member= $service->calc_bonus(2, 3);
print"Topup Result";
print_r($member);
```

And this is my Service class

```
<?php
namespace Spektr\Libraries;

class Service 
{

    public function calc_bonus($mem_id, $prd_id, $mems=null) {

        $bonus =0;  
        if(is_null($mems)) 
            $mems=[];
        $upline_id=\Spektr\Model\Member::whereMemId($mem_id)->value('upline_id');
        if ($upline_id) {

            \Log::info("upline-id: ".$upline_id);
            $this->calc_bonus($upline_id, $prd_id, $mems);
        }
print"service class result :";
print_r($mems);
        return $mems;
    }
}
```

when I run topup.php, page result will show result from print_r($mems) and print_r($member) like this

```
service class result :Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [mem_id] => 2
            [price] => 5100
            [bonus] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [mem_id] => 1
            [price] => 5000
            [bonus] => 100
        )

)
service class result :Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [mem_id] => 2
            [price] => 5100
            [bonus] => 0
        )

)
Topup ResultArray
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [mem_id] => 2
            [price] => 5100
            [bonus] => 0
        )

)
```

Why the result on Topup.php is contain only one array ? Please help with my code,

I'm hoping the result from topup.php contains all member with member's upline

The structure of database data is like this

```
mem_id|upline_id|name
1         null    member A
2          1      member B
```

Thx

Comment: Lookimng at your code I wonder how it works at all. I sincerely ask you to review your code for yourself first, because it has some major problems...

Comment: You are not filling $mems ... Still, if you are going to do anything with it, you should either merge the results using $mems and the result value or use $mems as pass-by-ref and fill regularly...

Comment: @Raphioly-San : I've edited the code, your statement is the key "You are not filling $mems", 

So I add `$mems = $this->calc_bonus($upline_id, $prd_id, $mems);`

And it's worked, Thx

Answer (score 0):

$member is a variable in topup.php Declare it as an array

```
$service = new \Spektr\Libraries\Service();

$member  =  array();

$member= $service->calc_bonus(2, 3);
print"Topup Result";
print_r($member);
```

Tested your code, worked with above change.

Comment: yes, without $member =array() , it's also returning array but only one array, I expect $member contain 2 array because mem_id = 2 had upline_id.

Answer (score 0):

I've come to this solution base on @raphioly-san answer

```
<?php
namespace Spektr\Libraries;

class Service 
{

    public function calc_bonus($mem_id, $prd_id, $mems=null) {

        $bonus =0;  
        if(is_null($mems)) 
            $mems=[];
        $upline_id=\Spektr\Model\Member::whereMemId($mem_id)->value('upline_id');
        if ($upline_id) {

            \Log::info("upline-id: ".$upline_id);
            $mems= $this->calc_bonus($upline_id, $prd_id, $mems); //<<-- add variable $mems
        }
print"service class result :";
print_r($mems);
        return $mems;
    }
}
```